# How to get max double in list?? With only one output, using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, max

I have tried using .maxBy .max() and collection.Max and I have only been able to print with it stating every element is max

```
    val fileName = "src/products.txt"
    var products = HashMap<Int, Pair<String, Double>>()

    var inputFD = File(fileName).forEachLine {
    var pieces = it.split(",")

    println("Item#     Description     Price")
    println("-----     -------------   ------")
       for ( (pro,ducts) in products.toSortedMap() ) {

          var pax = mutableListOf(ducts).maxBy { it -> it.second }
          var highest = listOf<Double>(ducts.second).max()

          println("The highest priced record is ${highest}")
       }
```

the file is set up like this (111, shoe, 9.99)

output looks like this
The highest priced record is [(pants, 89.99)]
The highest priced record is [(shoes, 49.99)]

Comment: `val maxPriceProduct = products.maxBy { it.value.second }` ?

Comment: Awesome! it worked! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to print the value within the for-loop, hence it is printing it for every product. Also the variable is initialized everytime in the loop, so every value would be max.

Here is the right approach. Note that you can solve it without using mutable variables.

```
val fileName = "src/products.txt"
val products = File(fileName).readLines()  //read all lines from file to a list
        .map { it.split(",") }     // map it to list of list of strings split by comma
        .map { it[0] to it[1].toDouble() } // map each product to its double value in a Pair
        .toMap() // convert list of Pairs to a Map

println("Item#     Description     Price")
println("-----     -------------   ------")

products.keys.forEachIndexed { index, desc ->
    println("$index\t$desc\t${products[desc]}")
}
println("The highest priced record is ${products.maxBy { it.value }}")
```

Comment: Thank you, your advice help a lot. I must have been too tired, I didn't think about the loop. I couldn't get the answer above to work completely but it did help me work through it. I get an error for data type.

Comment: I received the wrong data type I assume because it was a list of errors. Due to my lack of experience, I'm not sure how to fix it.